# Validate In-Line Edits in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I need to validate inline editing in NetSuite.

I already have a Client Script in place that works great when editing the record normally.

I tried adding a User Event script that on the before save function that validates the record, but it appears this is ignored with inline editing.

Has anybody ran into this before?

Any insight you can provide would be helpful. Thanks!

Edits:

The relevant code from the UE script:

```
function beforeSubmit(type){
    if (type == "create" || type == "edit" || type == "xedit") {
        var status = nlapiGetContext().getSetting("SCRIPT", "...");
        var amount = Number(nlapiGetContext().getSetting("SCRIPT", "..."));

        var nr = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        var entitystatus = nr.getFieldValue("entitystatus");
        var projectedtotal = Number(nr.getFieldValue("projectedtotal"));
        if (entitystatus == status && projectedtotal >= amount) {
            var statusText = nr.getFieldText("entitystatus");
            var message = "ERROR...";
            throw nlapiCreateError("...", message, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This applies to the opportunity record.

The field being validated is Projected Total with id `projectedtotal`.

Comment: which field are you inline updating and on what record type? also, can you check your script deployment if it is not in Testing?

Comment: The field is Projected Total (projectedtotal), record is opportunity. Just double-checked deployment. It is released and works when the record is edited normally.

Comment: as per documentation, inline editable fields do fire user events, the only option you are left with is to open a support with NetSuite

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll open a ticket and report back when I hear something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake, I misunderstood how `xedit` handled `nlapiGetNewRecord()`. Calling `nlapiGetNewRecord` when in xedit only returns the edited fields, not the entire record. Thus, the if statement was never true in xedit mode, because either the amount or the status would be null (it was very unlikely the user would edit both at the same time, and validation relies on both these fields' values).

I edited the code to lookup the field value if it is not present in the new record. Now everything works as expected!

Thanks everyone for the help!

For reference, the corrected code is below.

```
function beforeSubmit(type){
    if (type == "create" || type == "edit" || type == "xedit") {
        var status = nlapiGetContext().getSetting("SCRIPT", "...");
        var amount = Number(nlapiGetContext().getSetting("SCRIPT", "..."));

        var nr = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        //Attempt to get values normally
        var entitystatus = nr.getFieldValue("entitystatus");
        var projectedtotal = Number(nr.getFieldValue("projectedtotal"));

        var id = nr.getId();

        //If values were null, it's likely they were not edited and
        //thus not present in nr. Look them up.
        if(!entitystatus){
            entitystatus = nlapiLookupField("opportunity", id, "entitystatus");
        }
        if(!projectedtotal){
            projectedtotal = Number(nlapiLookupField("opportunity", id, "projectedtotal"));
        }

        if (entitystatus == status && projectedtotal >= amount) {
            var message = "ERROR...";
            throw nlapiCreateError("101", message, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user event are you checking the value of the type parameter.  For inline editing, the value of the type is 'xedit'.

Comment: Yes. I'm checking for create, edit, and xedit. If I do an inline edit, then open the record and save, the user event works properly. Just seems to be ignored when inline editing.