# I am trying to validate that one date is between 2 other dates using suitescript when being edited inline on a saved search

Tags: javascript, validation, netsuite, suitescript

Validate inline edit on a saved search, suitescript 1.0

I have the validation working for non-inline edits when the change is made on the record itself. I am looking to get the same validation online when an edit is made on the saved search as an inline edit. I have 3 date fields, a ship, cancel, and expected date. The cancel date needs to be between the ship date and the expected date. I am using the following code. TNHelper.inRageDateCheck just returns true if the 3rd date is between the first two dates.

[Edit Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4_zN-t1i8Nd9Qwz1o1iGdCS9WqolVxq/view?usp=sharing)

```
function saveRecord_Functions() {
    var noProblem = true, alertmsg = '';

    // EXPECTED DATE Required only in Form "TN Purchase Order"
    if (nlapiGetFieldValue('customform') != 102 || type != 'xedit') return true;

    var helper = new TNHelper();
    if (helper.inRageDateCheck(nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_startshipdate')
            ,nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_tn_po_expecteddate')
            ,nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_tn_po_canceldate'))){
        noProblem = true;
    }else{
        alertmsg = 'Cancel Date must be between Start Ship Date and Expected Date.';

    }   
    if(alertmsg.length>0){
        alert(alertmsg);
        return;
    }
    return noProblem;
}
```

I would like it to pop alertmsg when an invalid cancel date is put into the field and attempted to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work on the client script save record entry point; the xedit context validation is only available for user event scripts. You can add validation with a UE script, but unfortunately you will not be able to send an alert to the user via alert(). For more information on how to do this, check out this question: [Validate In-Line Edits in Netsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977092/validate-in-line-edits-in-netsuite)